# Use activityIndicator as image placeholder

Tags: ios, swift, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I use UIImageView+AFNetworking.swift in my project, and to load image to imageView with placeholder, i use this code:

```
imageCell!.imageView.setImageWithUrl(NSURL(string: post.image)!, placeHolderImage: UIImage(named: "PlaceholderIMG"))
```

How can i replace the `PlaceholderIMG` with a `activityIndicator` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `setImageWithURLRequest` from UIImageView+AFNetworking.swift instead of your solution.  So here's a rough example:

```
// create a UIActivityIndicatorView with the 
let ai = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: cell.imageView.frame)
// Add the UIActivityIndicatorView as a subview on the cell
cell.addSubview(ai)
// Start the UIActivityIndicatorView animating
ai.startAnimating()
// Load the remote image with this different API, and send nil as the placeholder
cell.imageView?.setImageWithURLRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: post.image)),
    placeholderImage: nil,
    success: { (request, response, image) -> Void in
        // on completion, stop it and remove it
        ai.stopAnimating()
        ai.removeFromSuperview()
        cell.imageView?.image = image
    },
    failure: { (request, response, error) -> Void in
        // on completion, stop it and remove it
        ai.stopAnimating()
        ai.removeFromSuperview()
})
```

Comment: It gave some errors, and i tried it like this: http://pastebin.com/ZbfDFT9u - Shows no errors, but the imageView has no image...

Comment: my bad, missed one line.  in the success block, you actually need to set the image in the cell.  i added it to my solution above, look for: cell.imageView?.image = image